# Can someone tell me what package `catch` comes from in the code below?

Tags: haskell

I'm interested in playing with this github [project](https://github.com/yihuang/haskell-json-rpc). There seems to be a missing dependency. Could someone tell me from [context](https://github.com/yihuang/haskell-json-rpc/blob/master/Network/JsonRpc/Server.hs) from what package `catch` comes from. Only `Control.Exception` comes to mind, but I don't think that's right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's pretty easy to tell in the case, since every import has either an import list or is qualified we see right away that `catch` isn't explicitly imported.

In haskell the functions that aren't explicitly imported are from `Prelude`. Here's a link to the [docs](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.4.2/html/libraries/base-4.5.1.0/Prelude.html#v%3acatch). You probably had some trouble finding it since it's removed in the latest version of Haskell in favor of the one you found in `Control.Exception`.
Have fun with project!

Comment: Hmm, I thought `catch` was to be used with `throw`, which is why it didn't make sense. Okay I'll use the one from 'Control.Exception`.

Comment: Well, I suppose it's time to fork.

Comment: Yeah... this is a breaking change that's bitten me again a few times.